# Will I be able to get my second boarding pass without having to go through security again?

Tags: tickets, international-travel, airport-security, connecting-flights

As a birthday gift, my friend who works for Alaska Airlines is  buying my ticket from the US west coast to the US east coast, and all I had to do was buy my ticket from the East coast to Italy. I'll be switching from Alaska to a Delta flight in Boston. Since my tickets were bought seperately, will I have to re-enter security in order to get my Delta boarding pass? If not, where can I get my new boarding pass in the airport?

Comment: As you are on a multi-ticket itinerary, you will have to re-check any hold luggage anyway, so getting your ticket is probably a small extra matter...?

Comment: wouldn't be surprised if Delta offers online checkin, allowing you to print your boarding pass at home before you set out. Same with Alaskan. Not sure about rechecking your luggage, maybe you can get it cross checked, I know it's pretty normal in other countries.

Comment: @jwenting What is pretty normal? That luggage is automatically re-checked for a second flight with a separate ticket on another airline without involving the passenger?

Comment: @Neusser I've had that happen more than once, yes. Usually within an alliance, tbh.

Comment: Does Delta fly to Italy from Boston? Is this a new route? Or the codeshare on Alitalia?

Answer (score 1):

In the US you can get boarding passes for all domestic flights either:

- The classic way - at the airline check-in counter
- at any of the self service kiosks once you enter the airport
- get it printed when you online check-in on the airline website
- on your phone in the airline's mobile app

So feel free to choose any option that suits your travel needs. BUT what would be a headache for you is your checked in luggage. I am 99% certain that your checked in luggage will not be transferred from the AA plane to the Delta plane. Instead you might have to collect your luggage from the baggage claim area and drop it off on the next airline's collection counter. If this does not seem to be a hassle for you then you are good to go, otherwise it's worth a try to call AA customer service and ask them about this particular scenario.

Now let's come to the more interesting part. If you are traveling just with a personal item + a hand carry you can USUALLY move on to the transit area once you arrive and wait for the next plane near the designated gate. BUT you would need to have the next boarding pass with you i.e. either check-in online and print it or use the airline app.

Comment: Keep in mind the OP is talking about Alaska Airlines as AA, not American Airlines which traditionally gets referred to as AA.  Delta and Alaskan have some code share and partnerships (though this is waning since DL now hubs out of Seattle), so the Alaska gate agent may check bags through.

Comment: Delta and Alaska  use adjacent terminals at Boston, so the OP can likely stay inside the secure area when changing flights, so no need to show the boarding pass until they get to the Delta gate.  And they could likely do the entire check in for the DL flight at the gate counter or the Delta service counter inside the sterile area (assuming only carry on or checked through bags).

Comment: @Tom you may be right. I based my answer on https://pro.delta.com/content/agency/mx/en/news/policy-update-archive/2016/january-2016/delta-confirms-through-check-baggage-policy--.html

Comment: @Tom Delta doesn't fly to Italy from Boston, so I would imagine this is the Alitalia flight to Rome (under a DL codeshare) operating out of terminal E. Last time I was at BOS the terminal C to E connector was not finished yet, but that was a while ago now.

Comment: @Calchas - I likewise haven't been there recently, but the airports website seems to indicate the two terminals are now connected inside the sterile area.